# How to use Beautiful Soup to select only one of multiple tables

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html document with 4 or 5 different tables.  The one I want has an attribute class = "data".  I can't figure out how to make BeautifulSoup return just that table.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)

t = soup.findAll('table', 'class="data"')
for table in t:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            print td
```

If I remove the 'class="data"' in the above, I get the results from every table.  Is it possible to select only the one with class = "data".  Or, is there some other way to iterate through the tables?

Comment: I can't find one... "<table class="data" style="width:100%;">
<tr class="title"><td colspan="4">Transactions Report</td></tr>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `class` atttribute as a dictionary as follow:

```
t = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'data'})
```

If you use bs4, you can use CSS Selector using `select` method:

```
t = css_soup.select("table.data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the following code :

```
t = soup.find_all('table', class_='data')
```

The attribute class need the under to refer

Comment: This didn't work.  The other answer (t = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'data'})) solved it.  The underscore doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake, the underscore is in the other side.